# How to use different jquery function of idangero swiper dependant on page template?

Tags: functions, jquery, page-template

I have struggled with adding the idangero swiper jquery plugin to my site, but have managed to produce the code below. This works very well but only on the one custom page template defined in the `function register_swiper()` part of the code below. However, I need to use the swiper on another set of pages using a different page template, use different options for the slider, as defined in `var mySwiper = $('.swiper-container').swiper({ mode:'horizontal',` such as `slidesPerView: 3`.

```
function register_swiper() {
wp_register_style( 'swiper-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/idangerous.swiper.css' );
wp_register_script( 'swiper-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/idangerous.swiper-2.1.min.js' , array( 'jquery' ) );
if ( is_page_template('Review.php')|| is_page_template('Comparison.php' )){
     wp_enqueue_style( 'swiper-css' );
     wp_enqueue_script( 'swiper-js' );
}
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_swiper' );

function print_my_inline_script() {
   if ( wp_script_is( 'swiper-js', 'done' ) ) { ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
             $(document).ready(function(){
var mySwiper = $('.swiper-container').swiper({
mode:'horizontal',
});
})

        </script>

 <?php } 
}

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'print__my_inline_script' );
```

I am really sorry if I have explained this badly, but I am not great at explaining these things, so if there is any more information you need in able to help please do ask!

Thanks a lot in advance!

Here is the link to the swiper website: 
http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/api.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really learn how to use debug mode in Wordpress. You should go and read this page: [Debugging Wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress). The reason being is this line of code

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'print__my_inline_script' );
```

If you had debug enabled, you would have seen a message like this

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback,

because your function name is `print_my_inline_script()` and you are hooking `print__my_inline_script` to `wp_footer`

Also, you should not use capital letters in template names, never.

You can extend the pages you want to load your script/style on by just adding `|| is_page_template('template name' )` to your existing conditions. You should also have a look at [conditional tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) and the `is_page()` condition

Comment: Hi thanks for replying, I am a little confused as to what the problem with using `print_my_inline_script()` is. Also, I have tried using `||` but with no luck, and this would not allow me to call a different jquery function but only enable the current function on the another page, so I am still a little confused. Any help would bee much appreciated! Thanks. @PieterGoosen

Comment: Look closely at your code, your function is `print_` while your hook is `print__`, note the double underscore in the one and single underscore in the other. Set debug to true in wp-config.php. You'll see you get a warning notice about this. Because of that syntax error your second set of code will not work

Comment: Ok that is working now, howver, I still cannot figure out how to load DIFFERENT versions of the jquery dependant on the page template. I have tried doing the piece of code again with a different piece of the javascript, but this does not work at all? If you could help that would be great thanks. @PieterGoosen

Comment: I don't understand your question " load DIFFERENT versions of the jquery dependant on the page template"

Comment: I am very sorry I am not great at explaining things! I have now fixed the problem by copying the chunk of code that has `print_my_inline_script()` in and changing that to just `print_my_code` and then changing the `mode:'horizontal',` to `mode:'vertical',` ! Thanks for all your help!

Comment: My pleasure, glad you could solve your problem. Enjoy! :-)